# CodeSynthesis : how to include files from <xsd>?

Tags: c++, include, xsd, codesynthesis

I generated c++-code from a XSD-scheme, now when i put that into a project, the compiler tells me that all `#include <xsd/...>` cannot be included. but i've added the include directory to the VC++-directories.

1 out of 100 errors:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xsd/cxx/config.hxx': No such file or directory
```

but they all more or less the same errors, all about `<xsd/...>`

the errors occur in the generated *.hxx file

What to do? How can i force to reimport them?

---

Comment: is the xsd directory a subdirectory of the VC++ directories? how is the path tree can you show us?

Comment: thx, i've set it like described in the tutorial. seems like the tutorial isnt correct at all. You can post an answer so i can acceppt it if you want

Comment: sure i will:-). can you tell which tutorial? maybe we can point out a good one if the current is not so good.

Comment: it's the README.txt from the CodeSynthesis-folder about how to set up Visual Studio, that also pops up after installation i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Like the directories are not a subdirectory of the VC++ directories.

Set it to become sub directories.

If you dont do this, you can include the full path and with `""` instead of `<>` in `#include`.

Comment: What is the full path? Can you help me with that?